# calling a webservice from angularjs from a sample which works in rest client

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I am trying to call a webservice from angularjs.
The webservice is working fine from Chrome Rest client but i am getting error from Angularjs which is inside an ionic application.
I am calling service from Rest Client like in the attached image and i am getting success.
[image: Rest Client]

But when i try to call the same service from angularjs post method,error is coming that Endpoint not found.
The way i am calling from angularjs-

```
$http({
                    method:"POST",
                    url:"http://xyz/service.svc/GetData",
                    headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'aaa',
                    'client_id': 'bbb',
                    'devicemetadata': 'ccc', 
                    'deviceID': 'ddd',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data:{"MethodName":"GetNominationDetails","ProgramID":"0","SessionID":"0","ParticipantID":"0","EID":"M123"}
                 })
            .success(function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log("success");
                def.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function(msg){
                console.log("failure iidealist"+msg);
                 def.reject(msg);
            });
```

Can anybody figure out the mistake.
I am taking care of access-origin issue in Ionic application.

Comment: does it fail on a physical device or in the browser?

Comment: it is failing in both.

Comment: can you try to access the same URL using a browser on your mobile device? see if they can reach each other.

Comment: its a post request,in rest client it is working...bt not from angularjs...

Comment: your error says that endpoint is not found, so regardless of the request being a post or a get request, the browser on the mobile device should at least reach the endpoint

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075398/rest-post-request-gives-end-point-not-found-error) might help you.But that is in c#.not in angular JS